# Is this the canonical way to iterate over a set of values?

Tags: iterator, rust

I have a type with an enumerable set of values:

```
struct MyType(u32);
```

I can define an iterator over the set of values:

```
struct MyTypeIter {
    m: MyType,
}
impl Iterator for MyTypeIter {
    type Item = MyType;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if (self.m).0 < 0xffffffff {
            (self.m).0 += 1;
            Some(MyType((self.m).0 - 1))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
impl MyTypeIter {
    fn new() -> MyTypeIter {
        MyTypeIter { m: MyType(0) }
    }
}
```

Is this really the canonical way to do it? What if we have several natural orders (like iterating over permutations or combinations in lex/colex order)?

Comment: Your `MyTypeIter` doesn't ever yield the value `MyType(0)`.

Comment: Note that I am subtracting 1. Anyway this is not real code, just an oversimpliefied example.

Comment: Ok, so it never yields `MyType(u32::max_value())`. Simplified examples are fine, I just don't want you to be unaware of the bug.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What if we have several natural orders (like iterating over permutations or combinations in lex/colex order)?

Implement different iterator types for different iteration orders. Instead of a `MyTypeIter` you can have multiple iterator types such as `MyTypePermutationIter` and `MyTypeCombinationIter`.

The standard library takes this approach in many places. Take for example the string slice type [`str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html). You can naturally iterate over the bytes of a string, over UTF-8 characters, or over lines (to name a few examples). For this purpose `str` exposes different methods:

- [`bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.bytes) returns the [`Bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Bytes.html) iterator
- [`chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) returns the [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) iterator.
- [`lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines) returns the [`Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Lines.html) iterator.